# File doesn't exist after writing it

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the following code:

```
try
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(filename,           FileMode.OpenOrCreate, store));
        Console.WriteLine(name + ";" + positions + ";" + courier + ";" + deliverydate + ";" + submissiondate);
        output.Flush();
        output.Close();
        output.Dispose();
     }
 }
 catch (Exception exf)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Error occured while saving your delivery. Unregistered Delivery");
 }
```

Where I save a string in a file. But when I try to read it right after writing it, the file seems like it doesn't exist.

```
 try
 {
     using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     {
         using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)))
         {
              while (reader.Peek() != -1)
              {
                  MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadLine());
              }
              reader.Close();
          }
      }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't exist?

Comment: please test something like to make a outprint then you going in the funktion

Comment: i dont know stream very well but there du you print in a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write data not in file but in console. Change your code from this

```
Console.WriteLine(name + ";" + positions + ";" + courier + ";" + deliverydate + ";" + submissiondate);
```

to that:

```
output.WriteLine(name + ";" + positions + ";" + courier + ";" + deliverydate + ";" + submissiondate);
```

Comment: An elegant method could be `output.WriteLine(String.Join(";", new[] {name, positions, courier, deliverydate, submissiondate}))`